# subprocess.POpen in Pyton 3.10 [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

I just upgraded my web app to Python 3.10, and the following used to work before:

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(['scp', '-i', self.key, src, dest],
                                   shell=False,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but now I am getting

**[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scp'**

What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, needed to specify the full path to scp!!

So it would be:

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/scp', '-i', self.key, src, dest],
                                   shell=False,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: This isn't _always_ necessary, but it is always the recommended practice; see the big red warning section in https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: ...as that documentation recommends, using `shutil.which('scp')` in the first argument lets your code still work on platforms where scp isn't in `/usr/bin`.